# Mixing Java and Kotlin with Maven, can't find symbol

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, kotlin, vaadin

I'm trying to add some Kotlin classes into my existing Java project under Vaadin Framework (v 8.4.5).

I've fully read the tutorial on [how to mixing java and Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/mixing-java-kotlin-intellij.html), and I've successfully created a Kotlin class inside my existing Java Project.

The new Kotlin class is inside my project (ofc I've cutted away all code for privacy)

```
package it.projectName.utils

import it.projectName.otherClasses

class SecurityUtils (user: User) {
    //various val and var, and of course the isCrypted calculated val

    init {
        if(!isCrypted){
            //encrypt user password
        }
    }
}
```

Now I'm using this Kotlin class inside my Java class with

```
import it.projectName.utils.SecurityUtils;
public class UserDao{
    //[... other code ...]
    SecurityUtils securityUtils = new SecurityUtils(user);
}
```

Everything is fine, I don't get any compiler error.
But when I try to run my project with maven with `jetty:run` , it throws an error:

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /C:/pathToClass/UserDao.java:[9,36] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class SecurityUtils
  location: package it.projectName.utils
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
```

The line he's referring to is `import it.projectName.utils.SecurityUtils;`

I've checked my `pom.xml`, everything looks fine there aswell:

```
    <properties>
        <kotlin.version>1.2.61</kotlin.version>
        <kotlin.compiler.incremental>true</kotlin.compiler.incremental>
    </properties>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-test</artifactId>
        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>compile</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceDirs>
                            <sourceDir>src/main/java</sourceDir>
                            <sourceDir>src/main/kotlin</sourceDir>
                        </sourceDirs>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>test-compile</id>
                    <phase>test-compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test-compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceDirs>
                            <sourceDir>src/main/java</sourceDir>
                            <sourceDir>src/main/kotlin</sourceDir>
                        </sourceDirs>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <jvmTarget>1.8</jvmTarget>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

What I'm missing?
Thanks

Comment: Did you check this ? - https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-maven.html#compiling-kotlin-and-java-sources

Comment: @SachithDickwella yes, I've also followed that instructions

Comment: You haven't set the source directories and target directories yet. Also set this
`<properties>
    <kotlin.compiler.incremental>true</kotlin.compiler.incremental>
</properties>`

Comment: @SachithDickwella I've added the code as you suggested, both in properties and in configuration (I've edited the question and I've added there aswell), but I still get the same error. Have I done that correctly?

Comment: @SachithDickwella is required to put my kotlin classes into a dedicated folder? Atm I've putted them into the java folder (main/java)

Comment: Yes, in the main folder tree, there should be two folders `main/java` and `main/kotlin`. As you put your java packages inside the java folder, need to put kotlin packages in kotlin folder. Also should they mention in the pom.xml similar to the example. I never had a problem doing that way. It works for me.

Comment: @SachithDickwella that did the trick!!! Thanks so much! Btw I cannot find this information nowhere in the documentation, that solved my problem!  If you want to post an answer with this solution I will flag that as valid answer. Thanks again

Comment: I wish I could structure my source tree by logical purpose of the code, rather than by the language it's written in. Perhaps it would be simpler to bribe the JDK developers to make Java recognise Kotlin source 

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We have to use two different source directories for each, under the `src/main` directory. (I'm talking about maven folder structure).

For example for Java, it is `src/main/java` and for Kotlin, it's like `src/main/kotlin`.

As per the documentation [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-maven.html), under topic of **Compiling Kotlin and Java sources**, JetBrains provides comprehensive maven plugin to declare each of aforementioned directories as their corresponding source directory. So then the compiler can detect both source directories, and in the building process, able to copy respective binary files to the class path.

Here is that maven plugin declaration,

```
<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>compile</id>
                <goals> <goal>compile</goal> </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <sourceDirs>
                        <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDir>
                        <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</sourceDir>
                    </sourceDirs>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>test-compile</id>
                <goals> <goal>test-compile</goal> </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <sourceDirs>
                        <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/test/kotlin</sourceDir>
                        <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/test/java</sourceDir>
                    </sourceDirs>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <executions>
            <!-- Replacing default-compile as it is treated specially by maven -->
            <execution>
                <id>default-compile</id>
                <phase>none</phase>
            </execution>
            <!-- Replacing default-testCompile as it is treated specially by maven -->
            <execution>
                <id>default-testCompile</id>
                <phase>none</phase>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>java-compile</id>
                <phase>compile</phase>
                <goals> <goal>compile</goal> </goals>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>java-test-compile</id>
                <phase>test-compile</phase>
                <goals> <goal>testCompile</goal> </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Also, I personally recommend following property must be there to increase the speed of build process.

```
<properties>
    <kotlin.compiler.incremental>true</kotlin.compiler.incremental>
</properties>
```

This one had worked for me pretty well, even if you creating a maven project with modules.